# How to start two activities where One should go in Pause state while other should be in running mode?

Tags: android

I want to execute two activities from one activity, where One should go in Pause state and other will go in Running mode.

Answer (score 0):

Start the 2nd Activity from the first Activity.

Start the 3rd Activity from the onCreate of 2nd Activity.

Now you will see 3rd Activity and on closing this activity 2nd Activity will show up.

Comment: this will show the intermediate screens for a moment, So I dont want like this. Thanks

Comment: I don't think so... Otherwise use answer given by @Tareq

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        PuasedActivity.class);
    startActivity(in);

    in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                         RunningActivity.class);
    startActivity(in);
```

When you press the back button the paused activity will start.

Comment: Using this way control will directly go to RunningActivity, But it will not start the PausedActivity i.e. onCreate() of Paused activity will not be started. Thanks

Comment: @user3676087 No it will. Try it.

Comment: It executes the Oncreate() method od PausedActivity When I press back button from RunningActivity.

Comment: @user3676087 What is your reference? How do you know that?

Comment: @Treq, I have checked, It does not run the Oncreate() of PausedActivity. OnCreate() Runs when I comeBack from the RunningActivity.

Comment: @user3676087 Then start each activity from a thread and make one run 100 milliseconds after the other.